# How do I redirect wordpress installed in /blog to new different domain?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want to point x.com/blog to y.com domain, I couldn't.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ y.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I haven't tried it this way. What path should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

to redirect an old path to new path, you can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?old-path/(.*)$ /new-path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, that's not the answer I'm looking for. If you examine the issue carefully, I want to redirect the directory located in another domain to the root directory of a different domain.